# convert set to object

Tags: javascript

I have a set which needs to be converted into an object with the set's unique values as the object keys and an empty string as each element's value in the object.

Here is the set I'm working with:

```
const uom = new Set(['inches', 'centimeters', 'yards', 'meters']);
```

I've tried this:

```
const uomObj = {...[...uom]};
console.log(uomObj);
```

Which yields this:

```
Object {
  "0": "inches",
  "1": "centimeters",
  "2": "yards",
  "3": "meters",
}
```

but that does not match the desired result of:

```
Object {
  "inches": "",
  "centimeters": "",
  "yards": "",
  "meters": "",
}
```

Can this be achieved with an ES6 approach?  If so, how?

Comment: Any solution will be an ES6 solution, because that's when Set was added to the language.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can use [`Array.from`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/from) with a mapping function to convert each value inside your set into an object and then use [`Object.assign()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/assign) with the [spread syntax](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Spread_syntax) to merge the array of objects into a single resulting object like so:

```js
const uom = new Set(['inches', 'centimeters', 'yards', 'meters']);
const res = Object.assign(...Array.from(uom, v => ({[v]:''})));
console.log(res);
```

Answer (score 1):

Create an object, then loop over the values in the set and create a property for each one. The `reduce` method is probably the most compact way to do that.

```js
const uom = new Set(['inches', 'centimeters', 'yards', 'meters']);
const result = Array.from(uom).reduce( (a,c) => { a[c]=""; return a; }, {});
console.log(result);
```

Answer (score 1):

Here's one way:

```
[...uom].reduce((o, u) => {
  o[u] = '';
  return o;
}, {})
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `Array.prototype.reduce` to get the elements from the set and accumulate it in an object:

```js
const uom = new Set(['inches', 'centimeters', 'yards', 'meters']);
const getObjectFromSet = (set) => {
return [...set].reduce((r, k) => {r[k] = ""; return r; },{});
}
console.log(getObjectFromSet(uom));
```

You can also use the `Object.fromEntries` for ES6+ code:

```js
const uom = new Set(['inches', 'centimeters', 'yards', 'meters']);
const getObjectFromSet = (set) => {
  return Object.fromEntries(Array.from(set, (k) => [k, ""]));
}
console.log(getObjectFromSet(uom));
```

Answer (score 0):

For anyone like myself who was looking for the reverse of this for something similar to the below

```
 Object {
  "length": "inches",
  "length": "centimeters",
  "length": "yards",
  "length": "meters",
    }
```

This code worked for me

```
        const mySet = new Set(['inches', 'centimeters', 'yards', 'meters']);
        let newArr = [];

        const setToObj = [...mySet].map(el => {
          newArr.push({ 'length': el });
        });
```